# Sphinx and reStructuredText: pass parameter in include directive

Tags: python, include, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am a newbie in Sphinx and reStructuredText.

I have n rst files in which I would like to insert a similar text (**not code**):

`Hello Earth.`

or

`Hello Mars.`

or

`Hello Saturn.`

My idea is to include in my rst files a common rst file.

`.. include:: planet.rst`

with planet.rst and a placeholder for the planet in this file:

`Hello <planet>.`

My current solution is:
planet.rst:

```
Hello Earth.
Hello Mars.
Hello Saturn.
```

and in my n rst files, e.g. for planet Mars:

```
.. include:: planet.rst
   :start-line: 1
   :end-line: 2
```

I am looking for a better solution.

I didn't found a purposeful option for the include directive in http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html

How can I pass a parameter (variable/value) to the included file to replace placeholder?

Thank's for your hints Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive for ["Replacement Text (`replace`)"](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#replacement-text) should work with included files.

`planet.rst`:

```
Hello |planet|.
```

`earth.rst`:

```
.. |planet| replace:: Earth

.. include:: planet.rst
```

Comment: Yes, this is it what I need. Thank you.

Comment: The solution works, but I get a warning in console output: _<my_path>\panet.rst:2: WARNING: Undefined substitution referenced: "planet"_. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I can't help, I can't reproduce this message. Do you have any more details (exact code and software versions, for example)?

Comment: I work with Python2.7 and Sphinx v1.8.5

Here are my file: my_module.rst:

`.. _my_module:

.. |planet| replace:: Earth

.. include:: planet.rst`

and planet.rst:
`Hello |planet|`

Comment: For information: code in a comment is not easily readable if it is supposed to have new lines, it would probably have been better to edit your original question with an update. Anyway, with _Sphinx_ I can reproduce it (I had tried this with _docutils_ only so far). Sphinx behaves differently than docutils, and is more sensitive to the combination of `include` and `replace`. In your situation I would probably ask the Sphinx maintainers directly, they might have better advice or it might be a bug.