# Combining replace and include in reStructuredText / Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I have been searching for a solution to this, but have just got even more confused!

I have a use case in my documentation to replace many instances of a name for a piece of equipment. I had been using the reST  directive `replace`, so for instance:

```
.. |model| replace:: modelname
```

That works fine, but I reuse much of my documentation for different models, so what I really need to do is keep the model name in a text or reST file so that I don't have to go through all my source files to update. Something like:

```
.. |model| replace:: modelname.rst
```

Hope you follow that. I know you can include the contents of a file using the `include` directive, but I can't figure out how to achieve my use case.

Can anyone shed any light on how I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: ...I did find a related thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930190/sphinx-and-restructuredtext-pass-parameter-in-include-directive

which is similar to what I am looking to do, but I can't figure out how to apply this solution in my use case.

I'm new to reST (and StackOverflow), so feeling my way!

Comment: Is it `rst_epilog`/`rst_prolog` that you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214302/407651

Comment: Thank you so much! `rst_prolog` worked perfectly!